# How to retrieve several rows from database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Okay, so I've made a new project which allows users to send messages to each other. I've almost got it finished, just a few things need to be cleared up.

I've successfully allowed the user to send the message (via mysql). Now Im at the part where Im supposed to retrieve the message and display it in the form; this is where Im stuck. It'd be easy to do if the user has only 1 message in the database, but what if he had more than 1? How would I retrieve them all and display them in the form. Im using this query:

```
SELECT ToID
FROM Message
WHERE (ID LIKE @ID)
```

What it does is check the database for any messages containing the recipient as the user's ID. If the database does in fact contain any message, then the program will display them in the textboxes. But in the case if more than 1 message, how would the database display them in the form? The form has textboxes for:

1. Sender
2. Subject
3. Date.

This is the query I hoped to use for retrieving the message:

```
SELECT ID, Title, Body, Date, FromUsername
FROM Message
WHERE (ID LIKE @ID)
```

Please help? Any other solutions are fine as long as its easy to understand(im new to vb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, why not use a list box instead of a textbox to display the messages. That way it doesn't matter how many messages there are, they will just keep getting added to listbox.

Something like:

```
For Each s as String in messageList
listbox1.items.add(s)

Next
```

**Edit:**

Retrieve the data and then bind it to the listbox - I've never really worked with mysql so I've lifted the code from a google search - it should get you started though.

```
dim table as new DataTable("table1")

' Create a Connection
using conn as new MysqlConnection("...connectionstring")
    conn.Open() ' Open it

    ' Create a new Command Object
    using cmd as new MysqlCommand("SELECT ID, Title, Body, Date, FromUsername FROM Message WHERE (ID LIKE @ID)", conn)

        ' Create a DataAdapter
        ' A DataAdapter can fill a DataSet or DataTable
        ' and if you use it with a CommandBuilder it also
        ' can persist the changes back to the DB with da.Update(...)
        using da as new MysqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            da.Fill(table) ' Fill the table
        end using

    end using
end using

' A Binding Source allows record navigation
dim bs as new BindingSource(table, nothing)

' You can bind virtually every property (most common are "text" "checked" or "visible"
' of a windows.forms control to a DataSource
' like a DataTable or even plain objects



ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Message"
ListBox1.ValueMember = "ID"
ListBox1.DataSource = table2
```

Comment: Okay, that might work.. But how would I let it know what to add? How would I bring the rows from the database into the listbox? I only know how to bring 1 row :S Please bear with me Im still a beginner..